# Unit test by skipping library functions for code coverage

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, mstest

I am trying to create a unit test in MS Test for a CMS application, wherein I have minority number of function that I wrote in my solution, the majority of the functions came along with CMS framework.

Issue:

When I take the code coverage it shows less than 1 percentage. But this coverage is meaningless.

Question:

How can I find coverage for only the functions that I wrote skipping the library functions that came along with cms framework?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure which assemblies your code coverage should look for.

You need to edit `.runsettings` file for the Unit tests and add this

```xml
<ModulePaths>
  <Exclude>
   <ModulePath>Name of the dll goes here</ModulePath>
   <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
  </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```

For more information refer the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj159530.aspx

Comment: If this works to exclude the CMS calls purely via Configuration, it's better than my answer +1

Comment: yea, I hope, need to check

Comment: There is a catch here, the unit is entire DLL, what if I have written functions inside that DLL? how to ignore the function which I have not written in that DLL?

Comment: I think that Adding only assemblies which are needed to be unit tested in the ModulePath and then again filtering by applying ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute will help you as said by @JeremyThompson.

Comment: ExcludeFromCodeCoverage need to be applied in CMS framework library code, but I don't want to alter framework code, is there anything like IncludeinCodeCoverage where I can give in my code?

Comment: Will this work for you

Including only specific functions

<Functions>  
  <Include>  
    <!-- Include methods in the Fabrikam namespace: -->  
    <Function>^Fabrikam\..*</Function>  
    <!-- Include all methods named EqualTo: -->  
    <Function>.*\.EqualTo\(.*</Function>  
  </Include>  
  <Exclude>  
    <!-- Exclude methods in a class or namespace named UnitTest: -->  
    <Function>.*\.UnitTest\..*</Function>  
  </Exclude>  
</Functions>

Comment: Let me try that looks promising

Comment: Did that work for you, if yes can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116(v=vs.100).aspx) attribute you can use.

You may need to isolate the CMS calls to a class or methods that you can decorate with this Attribute to skip the library functions.

Comment: I am not sure, I can alter the framework code, I need to keep the framework code as it is and get the coverage excluding the framework code.

Comment: The idea was a middle layer that excluded the CMS layer. @Ipsit answer looks better for what you want.